# UISplitViewController on iPhone: pop to / show primary view from detail view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I´m using the new iOS 8 UISplitViewController. If I run it on iPhone I have the following problem:

My primary view controller triggers a detail view controller to show. The detail view controller pushes a new view controller to the UINavigationController stack in the detail view.

Now I have the problem if I want to pop back to the primary view controller from the new view controller.

How can I do this

```
[self.navigatonController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

does not work.
I want to show the primary view controller on the iPhone. So I have to pop two views back.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 41):

UIViewControllers have a "splitViewController" property, so you can get a reference to the appropriate navigation controller through that - and then call popViewControllerAnimated.

Here it is in Swift (included somewhere in the detail view controller):

```
if let navController = splitViewController?.viewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController {
    navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: I prefer not to disclose how much time I wasted on this. Thank you so much--this worked great for me.

Comment: Thanks, pal! Lifesaver!

Comment: Hal-le-lu-ur. That is not obvious.

Answer (score 10):

I just found a solution on Apple Developer Forum:
[How to manually 'pop' back to MasterViewController in UISplitViewController on iPhone](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1011867#1011867)

> The old (and maybe still valid) recommendation is to let the Master
>   view intiate the 'pop". In order to do this the detail view needs to
>   inform the master view about the press of your custom button. This can
>   be achieved by defining a protocol, where the master view is the
>   delegate and the detail view has a variable called 'delegate'. When
>   the master pushes the detail view it sets this delegate variable to
>   self. Now the detail view has a hook to inform the master view.

This means to call from the (sub) detail view controller a primary view controller method:

(Sub) Detail View Controller:

```
UINavigationController *navCon = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
MyPrimaryViewController *primary = [navCon.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

[primary popToMaster];
```

Primary View Controller:

```
- (void)popToMaster
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: To be even simpler, you could replace the Detail VC method by :
UINavigationController *navCon = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[navCon popViewControllerAnimated: YES];

Comment: Also, in this case, it looks like there is no need to actually define a protocol and set the MasterVC as the delegate of the DetailVC, since you can get a grab directly to the navController of the primaryVC via [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]. Brilliant, anyway !

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me on the iPhone. I use UINavigationViewController as detail view controller for UISplitViewController. As I know the reason why 
`detailViewController.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` doesn't work is because root view controller for navigation controller is not the master view controller. Split view controller is the "navigation controller" for my detailViewController (UINavigationController).
I call this for pop to master view controller:

```
detailViewController.navigationController?.navigationCont
roller.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue !
As far as I understood, the splitViewController "looks" like a navigationController on iPhone ("collapsed" splitVC), but the detailVC is actually NOT on the same navigation stack as the masterVC anymore. That's why your "popToRootViewController" message does not work anymore.

For the moment, I didn't find a way. i will tell you if I find a solution.